# Invalid operands to binary expression when implementing iterator for a template doubly linked list

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, doubly-linked-list

I'm able to implement a template doubly linked list with some basic functions along with data inside of it. Then I proceed to implement an iterator to get access to the data inside the nodes of the linked list. When I implement the iterator, there are no compile-time errors shown in the iterator files. However, I've encountered problems when I try to use the operations of the iterator in main.cpp file(the != operator show the error: Invalid operands to binary expression) Was there something wrong with my implementation of the iterator? Can you help me with this?

LinkedList.h:

```
//
// Created by baoto on 9/29/2020.
//

#ifndef LINKEDLIST_TEMPLATE_LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_TEMPLATE_LINKEDLIST_H
#include <iostream>
#include "Node_iterator.h"
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class LinkedList {
private:
    Node<T>* head;
    Node<T>* tail;
    unsigned int size = 0;
    Node<T>* find (const T& item);
public:
    typedef Node_iterator<T> iterator;
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
    void remove(Node<T>* node);
    bool isEmpty();
    void remove(const T& item);
    int givelist_size();
    void push_back(const T &item);
    void push_front(const T &item);
    void insertAfter(T search, T item);
    void insertBefore(T search, T item);
    LinkedList();
    void clearList();

    template<class S>
            friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const LinkedList<S> &list)
    {
        for (Node<T>* i = list.head; i != nullptr; i = i->next)
        {
            out << i->data << endl;
        }
        return out;
    }
};
#include "LinkedList.cpp"
#endif //LINKEDLIST_TEMPLATE_LINKEDLIST_H
```

LinkedList.cpp:

```
//
// Created by baoto on 9/29/2020.
//
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_TEMPLATE_LINKEDLIST_CPP
#define LINKEDLIST_TEMPLATE_LINKEDLIST_CPP
#include "LinkedList.h"
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::clearList() {
    Node<T>* walker;
    for (walker = head; walker != nullptr; walker = walker->next)
    {
        Node<T>* deleted = walker;
        delete deleted;
    }
    head = tail = nullptr;
    size = 0;
}
template<class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::isEmpty() {
    return (head->next == nullptr);
}

template<class T>
int LinkedList<T>::givelist_size() {
    return this->size;
}
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::remove(Node<T> *node) {
    if (node != head && node!= tail)
    {
        node->next->prev = node->prev;
        node->prev->next = node->next;
        delete node;
    }
    else if (size ==1)
    {
        delete head;
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
    }
    else if (node == head)
    {
        head = head->next;
        delete head->prev;
        head->prev = nullptr;
    }
    else if (node == tail)
    {
        tail = tail->prev;
        delete tail->next;
        tail->next = nullptr;
    }
    size--;
}
template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(): head(nullptr), tail(nullptr)
{

}
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::push_back(const T &item) {
    Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
    temp->data = item;
    temp->prev = tail;
    temp->next = nullptr;
    if (tail == nullptr)
    {
        tail = temp;
        head = temp;
    } else{
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
    size++;

}
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::push_front(const T &item) {
    Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
    temp->data = item;
    temp->next = head;
    temp->prev = nullptr;
    if (head == nullptr) {
        tail = temp;
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        head->prev = temp;
        head = temp;
    }
    size++;
}
template <class T>
Node<T>* LinkedList<T>::find(const T &item) {
    Node<T>* walker;
    for (walker = head; walker != nullptr; walker = walker->next)
        if (walker->data == item)
            return walker;
        return nullptr;
}
template <class T>

void LinkedList<T>::insertAfter(T search, T item) {
    Node<T>* prevNode;
    prevNode = find(search);
    if(prevNode != nullptr)
    {
        Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
        temp->data = item;
        temp->next = prevNode->next;
        prevNode->next = temp;
        temp->prev = prevNode;
        if (temp->next != nullptr)
            prevNode->next->prev = temp;
        else
        {
            temp = tail;
        }
    }
    size++;
}
template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insertBefore(T search, T item) {
    Node<T>* nextNode;
    nextNode = find(search);
    if (nextNode != nullptr)
    {
        Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
        temp->data = item;
        temp->prev = nextNode->prev;
        nextNode->prev = temp;
        temp->next = nextNode;
        if (temp->prev != nullptr)
        {
            temp->prev->next = nextNode;
        } else
        {
            head = temp;
        }
    }
    size++;
}
template <class T>
typename LinkedList<T>::iterator LinkedList<T>::begin() {
    iterator temp(head);
    return temp;
}
template <class T>
typename LinkedList<T>::iterator LinkedList<T>::end() {
    iterator temp(nullptr);
    return temp;
}

#endif
```

Node_iterator.h:

```
//
// Created by baoto on 10/9/2020.
//

#ifndef LINKEDLIST_TEMPLATE_NODE_ITERATOR_H
#define LINKEDLIST_TEMPLATE_NODE_ITERATOR_H

#include <iterator>
#include "Node.h"
template <class T>
class Node_iterator:public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,T> {
private:
    Node<T>* current;
public:
    T&operator*();
    Node_iterator operator++(int);
    Node_iterator& operator ++();
    Node_iterator operator --(int);
    Node_iterator& operator --();
    Node_iterator();
    Node_iterator(Node<T>* n);
    bool operator !=(const Node_iterator* n) const;
    bool operator == (const Node_iterator* n) const;
};

#include "Node_iterator.cpp"
#endif //LINKEDLIST_TEMPLATE_NODE_ITERATOR_H
```

Node_iterator.cpp:

```
//
// Created by baoto on 10/9/2020.
//
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_TEMPLATE_NODE_ITERATOR_CPP
#define LINKEDLIST_TEMPLATE_NODE_ITERATOR_CPP
#include "Node_iterator.h"
template <class T>
T& Node_iterator<T>::operator*() {
    return current->data;
}
template <class T>
Node_iterator<T> Node_iterator<T>::operator++(int) {
    Node<T>* temp = current;
    current = current->next;
    return *this;
}
template <class T>
Node_iterator<T>::Node_iterator() {
    current = nullptr;
}
template <class T>
Node_iterator<T>::Node_iterator(Node<T> *n) {
    current = n;
}
template <class T>
Node_iterator<T> Node_iterator<T>::operator--(int) {
    Node<T>* temp = current;
    current = current->prev;
    return *this;
}
template <class T>
bool Node_iterator<T>::operator!=(const Node_iterator<T> *n) const{
    return current != n->current;
}
template <class T>
Node_iterator<T>& Node_iterator<T>::operator++() {
    current = current->next;
    return *this;
}
template <class T>
Node_iterator<T>& Node_iterator<T>::operator--() {
    current = current ->prev;
    return *this;
}
template <class T>
bool Node_iterator<T>::operator==(const Node_iterator<T> *n) const {
    return current == n->current;
}

#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    LinkedList<int> list;
    list.push_back(2);
    list.push_front(3);
    list.insertAfter(2,5);
    list.insertBefore(3,6);
    LinkedList<int>::iterator iter;
    for (iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter)
    {
        cout <<*iter<<endl;
    }
    cout << list;

}
```

This is the error shown in the terminal, it's a big lengthy, that's why I didn't want to post it:

```
C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\main.cpp:11:36: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'LinkedList<int>::iterator {aka Node_iterator<int>}' and 'LinkedList<int>::iterator {aka Node_iterator<int>}')
     for (iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter)
                               ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\Node_iterator.h:26:0,
                 from C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\LinkedList.h:8,
                 from C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\main.cpp:2:
C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\Node_iterator.cpp:32:6: note: candidate: bool Node_iterator<T>::operator!=(const Node_iterator<T>*) const [with T = int]
 bool Node_iterator<T>::operator!=(const Node_iterator<T> *n) const{
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\Node_iterator.cpp:32:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'LinkedList<int>::iterator {aka Node_iterator<int>}' to 'const Node_iterator<int>*'
In file included from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/iosfwd:40:0,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/ios:38,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\main.cpp:1:
C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:221:5: note: candidate: template<class _StateT> bool std::operator!=(const std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)
     operator!=(const fpos<_StateT>& __lhs, const fpos<_StateT>& __rhs)
     ^~~~~~~~
C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:221:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\main.cpp:11:48: note:   'LinkedList<int>::iterator {aka Node_iterator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::fpos<_StateT>'
     for (iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter)
                                                ^
In file included from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/ios:40,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\main.cpp:1:
C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:456:5: note: candidate: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator!=(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
     operator!=(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
     ^~~~~~~~
C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:456:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\main.cpp:11:48: note:   'LinkedList<int>::iterator {aka Node_iterator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::pair<_T1, _T2>'
     for (iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter)
                                                ^
In file included from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/ios:40,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\main.cpp:1:
C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:311:5: note: candidate: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator!=(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator!=(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:311:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\main.cpp:11:48: note:   'LinkedList<int>::iterator {aka Node_iterator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'
     for (iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter)
                                                ^
In file included from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/ios:40,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\main.cpp:1:
C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:349:5: note: candidate: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator!=(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator!=(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:349:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\main.cpp:11:48: note:   'LinkedList<int>::iterator {aka Node_iterator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'
     for (iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter)
                                                ^
In file included from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/ios:40,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\main.cpp:1:
C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:1130:5: note: candidate: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator!=(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator!=(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:1130:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\main.cpp:11:48: note:   'LinkedList<int>::iterator {aka Node_iterator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>'
     for (iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter)
                                                ^
In file included from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/ios:40,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\main.cpp:1:
C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:1136:5: note: candidate: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator!=(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&)
     operator!=(const move_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:1136:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\main.cpp:11:48: note:   'LinkedList<int>::iterator {aka Node_iterator<int>}' is not derived from 'const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>'
     for (iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter)
                                                ^
In file included from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/string:41:0,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\baoto\CLionProjects\LinkedList_Template\main.cpp:1:
C:/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:158:5: note: candidate: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator!=(const std::allocator<_CharT>&, const std::allocator<_T2>&)
     operator!=(const allocator<_T1>&, const allocator<_T2>&)
     ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error copy/pasted?

Comment: Can you paste the complete error code? Also, it would make it easier for people to analyze faster if you can reduce the code to show the minimal example.

Comment: Never put `using namespace` in a header file. Please provide a [mre] with full compiler error messages

Comment: your comparison operators need to take const references not pointers

Comment: Did you mean ` bool Node_iterator<T>::operator!=(const Node_iterator<T> &n) const`? The posted code is showing ` bool Node_iterator<T>::operator!=(const Node_iterator<T> *n) const`